# Strange behavior. Jest gives `Cannot find module` when importing components with absolute paths

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jestjs, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

My jest config

```
  clearMocks: true,
  rootDir: '../../',
  cacheDirectory: 'cache',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  modulePaths: [
    '<rootDir>'
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/config/jest/setup.ts'
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules', 'src'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/mocks/file.js',
    '\\.s?css$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js', 'mjs', 'cjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'
  ],
  roots: [ '<rootDir>/src' ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$',
    '/vendor/'
  ],
  globals: {
    __IS_DEV__: false
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*unit.[jt]s?(x)',
  ],
```

I import `import { counterReducer, CounterStateSchema } from 'entities/Counter';`

All working fine when I rename the directory **entities** to any other directory. For Example ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'entity'] and others.

```
 PASS  src/aaaa/Counter/ui/__tests__/Counter.unit.tsx
   Counter
     ✓ test render Counter (106 ms)
```

But the directory named is **entities** test fails with error:

```
 FAIL  src/entities/Counter/ui/__tests__/Counter.unit.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

  Cannot find module 'entities/Counter' from 'src/app/config/redux/index.ts'
```

All other import working fine in my project and I have no idea, what it could be.

All other in my project working fine. Webpack, Storybook and so on.

I can't change the directory "entities" to other because I use Feature-Sliced Design. According to this methodology there should be this folder.

If I use relative path, it's work

```
-----script app/config/redux/index.ts------
import { counterReducer, CounterStateSchema } from '../../../entities/Counter';
----test result---
 PASS  src/entities/Counter/ui/__tests__/Counter.unit.tsx
  Counter
   ✓ test render Counter (102 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the repo in your comment in the github issue (really helpful btw).
Check your *node_modules* folder and you see package with name **entities**

As you use absolute path *'entities/someModule'*, jest resolves in node_modules first and finds! *entities* folder inside, but there is not *someModule* subfolder.

Why delete of jest-environment-jsdom did help?

It turned out that jest-environment-jsdom has following list of deps:

**jest-environment-jsdom -> @types/jsdom -> parse5 -> entities**.

So there is a reason why delete of jest-environment-jsdom helped. Entities folder is deleted from *node_modules* and jest resolves in *src* folder.
Use relative path also fixed.

Comment: Yes, of course, I use relative path, but this solution not graceful. For example, webpack or any other IDE resolve path properly.

Comment: you may use aliases and avoid relative paths if you want. You are right, webpack and jest use own resolvers so the result may be different. I have seen only your repo, there was only jest config and tried to explain that reason is in collision of pkg names inside node_modules and src folder.

Answer (score -1):

I found a bug in the jest-environment-jsdom package. Reported the bug to the jest team. Link to the bug [here](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14872)